# unnest a column and merge rows based on the unnested column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, dataframe, unnest

I have a table like this:

| ID | A's price | B's price | C's price | D's price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A,B,C | 1 | 2 | 3 | null |
| D | null | null | null | 4 |
| B | null | 10 | null | null |

what I want to achieve:

| ID | price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2,10 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 4 |

I tried `unnest(string_to_array(ID,','))` then `concat_ws(',', "A's price", "B's price", "C's price", "D's price")`, it doesn't give me the desired output.

Is there a way to achieve this in Postgres or do I need to switch to pandas?

Appreciate any ideas and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing - this data design is horrible. Think about normalization (at least 1NF) and then querying will be so much simpler.
Flatten the table in `t` subquery and then group by individual `id` and re-aggregate.

```sql
-- Test data
create table the_table 
(
 id text, 
 aprice numeric, 
 bprice numeric, 
 cprice numeric, 
 dprice numeric
);
insert into the_table values
('A,B,C', 1,    2,    3,    null),
('D',     null, null, null, 4),
('B',     null, 10,   null, null);

-- Query
select id,
  string_agg (case id 
     when 'A' then aprice 
     when 'B' then bprice 
     when 'C' then cprice
     when 'D' then dprice 
     end ::text, ',') as price
from
(
  select unnest(string_to_array(id, ',')) as id, aprice, bprice, cprice, dprice
  from the_table
) as t
group by id order by id;
```

Comment: this works perfectly in this case. thank you! wondering if there's way to avoid typing manually 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' in case when statement. instead, pull all of them in that column using SELECT statement, since I have a long list of ID.

Comment: Maybe use the table's DDL to shape the `when` list from it in a good text editor? No better idea right now.